# Issue with json string sending with get request in uri (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, get

I've got a json string "secret" and need to send it as a get parameter in uri.
Here's uri formatting:

```
  this.$el.find('#linkToProvablyFairPage').attr('href','');
    var hrefValue = '/provably_fair?';
    hrefValue += 'client_seed='+value.client_seed;
    hrefValue += '&hash_secret='+value.hash_secret;
    hrefValue += '&final_shuffle='+value.final_shuffle;
    hrefValue += '&secret='+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(value.secret));
    this.$el.find('#linkToProvablyFairPage').attr('href',hrefValue);
```

Now this string isn't sending and i get it empty on required page. How to fix this?

Comment: Example of secret json string : {"server_seed":"Hi3jTdmo1G8y6V8wildnlJ7ZABvzpY17","initial_shuffle":"MkHnqdxJvlzoL936maf8FE7jP14ghiDBeAIOwscpKGyubtr0N25C"}